# How to add values to columns if field is NaN upon split()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to set the values of fields to NaN using Pandas.

I have a spreadsheet file as an input and one of the columns has empty values which I filled with NaN values.

I am trying to split the first name with the suffix. I did use str.split().
But since there are NaN-value fields.

I encountered this error.

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

This is my sample DataFrame.

> input_data = {
>   ["John III","Snow"],["",""],["John","Snow"]}

This is my expected output

> expected_output = {["John","Snow","III"],["","",""],["John","Snow",""]}

This is my sample code

```
df[[fname[0][0],fname[1][0]]] = df[column].str.split('&', expand=True, n=1)
df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) is str else x)
df.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True)
df[[fname[0][0],fname[0][2]]] = df[fname[0][0]].str.split('\s+(?=Jr|Sr|JR|SR|II|III|IV)', expand=True, n=1)
```

I am just a newbie in Pandas and Numpy.

Comment: Can you add example of you input dataframe and desired output? Please take a look at how to provide [mcve].

Comment: `df.fillna(value=your_value_here, inplace=True)`?

Comment: @zipa I have added the input dataframe and desired output. Is it okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go about it like this:

```
input_data = [['John III', 'Snow'], ['', ''], ['John', 'Snow']]
split_data = [[k for j in i for k in j.split()] for i in input_data]
#[['John', 'III', 'Snow'], [], ['John', 'Snow']]

df = pd.DataFrame(split_data).fillna('')
#      0     1     2
#0  John   III  Snow
#1                  
#2  John  Snow      

df.values
#array([['John', 'III', 'Snow'],
#       ['', '', ''],
#       ['John', 'Snow', '']], dtype=object)
```